# Color of the lines does not change in JAVASCRIPT DATA INTERCEPTOR Apache Superset

Tags: javascript, geojson, polyline, apache-superset

I have a table with two columns. One column contains the hexcode for the color and the other one contains the geojson. I added the database in superset and wanted to change the color using javascript. Since I need multiple lines with different colors, I don't know what to do.

Do you guys have a solution?

Click for the picture

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing chart type from Deckgl Polygon to Deckgl Path.